# configure mod_proxy_wstunnel on apache 2.4.x

Tags: apache, configuration, centos

I want to use mod_proxy_wstunnel on my CentOS machine. So, I went through the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html) and it says that, this module is the part of Apache >= 2.4.5 but, I'm not able to use the Module and `mod_proxy_wstunnel.so` nowhere exists in my server.

I know, there are lots of related questions but those are all for older version of Apache.

Anyway, I'm using

**Apache 2.4.18**

**CentOS 6.7 (Final)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine where yourour 2.4.18 build came from, because it's not contemporary / part of Centos 6.

Whoever built or packaged it it needs to perform the routine task if including an additional standard module.

Comment: Hi covener! You're right. I've fixed the problem. btw, thank you for your response. I'll post it here in a while for others.